# Spring Data GemFire OQL

Tags: gemfire, spring-data-gemfire

Do you know if it is possible to do the following using springDataGemfire:

```
@Query("$1")
List<String> getQuery(String Query);
```

we are trying to build a dynamic query and then run it on GemFire

we are getting the below error :

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Result object returned from GemfireCallback isn't a SelectResult:

Best regards,
Farid

Answer (score 2):

Farid-

The SD[G] *Repository* infrastructure and extension for Pivotal GemFire, and in particular, the explicit OQL query using the `@Query` annotation, was never meant to be used in this way.

Essentially, you are attempting to use the SD *Repository* infrastructure to run "ad hoc" GemFire OQL queries, therefore, why not use the [GemfireTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data-gemfire/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/gemfire/GemfireTemplate.html#find-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) directly, or even GemFire's [QueryService](http://gemfire-90-javadocs.docs.pivotal.io/org/apache/geode/cache/query/QueryService.html#newQuery-java.lang.String-) API for this purpose?

What you are attempting to do is akin to using *Hibernate* for complex queries beyond mapping and ordinary queries (which is not really the purpose of *Hibernate*) when JDBC directly (or *Spring's* `JdbcTemplate`) is more appropriate for advance querying capabilities.

It is still possible to use a hybrid approach though, where the "provided" SD *Repository* infrastructure handles the majority of your application's data access patterns (e.g. CRUD, simple queries, etc) and you combine that with a ["custom" *Repository* implementation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations).

I have an example of such a "custom" *Repository* implementation for GemFire in my *Contacts Application* RI for SDG, [here](https://github.com/jxblum/contacts-application/tree/master/repository-example/src/main/java/example/app/repo/gemfire).  The [CustomerRepository](https://github.com/jxblum/contacts-application/blob/master/repository-example/src/main/java/example/app/repo/gemfire/CustomerRepository.java#L36) extends [CustomerRepositoryExtension](https://github.com/jxblum/contacts-application/blob/master/repository-example/src/main/java/example/app/repo/gemfire/CustomerRepositoryExtension.java), which is implemented in the [CustomerRepositoryImpl](https://github.com/jxblum/contacts-application/blob/master/repository-example/src/main/java/example/app/repo/gemfire/support/CustomerRepositoryImpl.java) class.  SD's *Repository* infrastructure picks up this "custom" implementation when creating the *Repository* proxy for the *CustomerRepository* interface.  In this case, I am having the ["custom *Repository* data access/query method](https://github.com/jxblum/contacts-application/blob/master/repository-example/src/main/java/example/app/repo/gemfire/CustomerRepositoryExtension.java#L38) call a GemFire Function (as can be seen [here](https://github.com/jxblum/contacts-application/blob/master/repository-example/src/main/java/example/app/repo/gemfire/support/CustomerRepositoryImpl.java#L46-L49)).

In your case, it is a simple matter to run the passed in, dynamic OQL query using the SDG `GemfireTemplate` or GemFire's `QueryService` API directly.

Hope this helps!
-John

Comment: Also note, in your particular example the OQL statement passed by the SD Repository infrastructure is the @Query annotation value (i.e. "$1") which is not a valid GemFire OQL (query) statement as handled by http://gemfire-90-javadocs.docs.pivotal.io/org/apache/geode/cache/query/QueryService.html#newQuery-java.lang.String-.  Essentially the query method (i.e. "getQuery(..)") parameter (i.e. "Query") value, the actual OQL (query) statement is the argument to http://gemfire-90-javadocs.docs.pivotal.io/org/apache/geode/cache/query/Query.html#execute-java.lang.Object:A-, which simply does not work.

Comment: 1 final comment... I added a test for you UC in my test project, here (https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/test/java/org/spring/data/gemfire/cache/RepositoryWithDynamicQueriesIntegrationTests.java).  I wrote 3 test cases...

Comment: The first test case, `springDataGemFireDynamicQueryTest` (https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/test/java/org/spring/data/gemfire/cache/RepositoryWithDynamicQueriesIntegrationTests.java#L127-L133) demonstrates your UC.  This test fails as expected based on "answer" above.

Comment: The second test case, `gemfireQueryTest` (https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/test/java/org/spring/data/gemfire/cache/RepositoryWithDynamicQueriesIntegrationTests.java#L117-L125) demonstrates what the SD[G] Repository abstraction/infrastructure and extension for Pivotal GemFire translates the "dynamic OQL query" method (e.g. "`getQuery(:String)`" to in terms of GemFire API calls. This test also fails!

Comment: Finally, the third test case, `springDataGemFireCustomDynamicQueryTest` (https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/test/java/org/spring/data/gemfire/cache/RepositoryWithDynamicQueriesIntegrationTests.java#L135-L142) demonstrates how you can properly handle "dynamic OQL queries" in your application Repositories.  This test **passes** as expected!